# Can I access a AWS S3 Bucket with "Bucket and objects not public" access via AWS Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

There is a S3 bucket that has "Bucket and objects not public" access. Within Athena, there is table that is pulling data from the S3 bucket successfully. However, I cannot pull the data from Athena to Quicksight. My conclusion is that it is because the S3 bucket has "Bucket and objects not public" access. Is this correct?

Is it the case that Athena has some kind of special access to the S3 bucket, but Quicksight doesn't?

Here is a crude illustration of the issue:

[image]

I'm a total beginner when it comes to AWS so I apologise for missing any information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that you can connect Amazon QuickSight to Athena, check the following settings:

- AWS resource permissions inside of Amazon QuickSight
- AWS IAM policies
- S3 bucket location
- Query results location

If S3 bucket location and Query results location are correct, you might have issues with Amazon QuickSight resource permissions. You have to make sure that Amazon QuickSight can access the S3 buckets used by Athena:

1. Choose your profile name. Choose **Manage QuickSight**, then choose **Security & permissions**.
2. Choose **Add or remove**.
3. Locate **Athena**, select it to enable Athena. (choose **Connect both**)
4. Choose the buckets that you want to access and click **Select**.
5. Choose **Update**.